# How to set permissions using chmod

Tags: android, bash, shell, file-permissions, chmod

I recently found a way to maintain root access on my android device using a dropbear SSH server that I modified to run at boot as root using init.d, a lil scripting magic & some config scripts I made. If you want you can check it out [here](http://goo.im/devs/Geofferey/Android%20Scripting%20Projects/persist_droid_sshd/v1.0/Universal-Flasher)... Anyways for an experiment I removed the su binary and Superuser.apk from the system. I've managed to get them copied back to the system, but I don't know how to set the appropriate permissions for the su binary. If I look in Super User app on another rooted phone and go to update, it shows `-rwsr -sr-x` as the permissions on the binary. How can I set these same permission manually & what do they mean? Specifically the s part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The s part is the `setuid` bit. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid):

> setuid and setgid (short for "set user ID upon execution" and "set
>   group ID upon execution", respectively) are Unix access rights flags
>   that allow users to run an executable with the permissions of the
>   executable's owner or group respectively and to change behaviour in
>   directories.

That permission string means:

- the owner can read, write, and execute
- users in the file's group can read and execute
- other users can read and execute
- the file has setuid set

You can set that specific permission by running `chmod 06755 /system/bin/su`. That's the octal (= "out of eight", like decimal is "out of ten" and hexadecimal is "out of sixteen") encoding for:

- the setuid bit (4) and setgid bit (2) = 6
- all permissions for the owner (7)
- read and execute for group (5)
- read and execute for others (5)

Comment: So if the s flag is set then it runs the executable as the user its owned by?

Comment: Yup, exactly. That's the whole point of su -- you need it to become root, so it needs to be able to, well, become root.

Comment: Cool, that got me up & running. Thanks for the help mate, appreciate it a lot. I learn better by asking questions.

Comment: Not a problem at all. Best of luck.

Comment: @Geofferey I noticed you were trying to edit this and people kept rejecting your edits. I looked it up and you were right -- what I proposed will also work, but it looks like `06755` is more correct on Android as opposed to desktop Linux systems. I've edited the post.

Comment: What is that leading zero before the other four digits (6775)?